# Update a record without first querying?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Lets say I query the database and load a list of items. Then I open one of the items in a detail view form, and instead of re-querying the item out of the database, I create an instance of the item from the datasource in the list.

Is there a way I can update the database record without fetching the record of the individual item?

Here is a sample how I am doing it now:

```
dataItem itemToUpdate = (from t in dataEntity.items
                                 where t.id == id
                                 select t).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then after pulling the record I update some values in the item and push the record back:

```
itemToUpdate.itemstatus = newStatus;
dataEntity.SaveChanges();
```

I would think there would be a better way to do this, any ideas?

Comment: It's not a terribly bad way o do things. Do you have concurrent access to that table?

Comment: I would think this is the usage that an ORM like EF is exactly there to serve. To allow operations within the context of the application to be performed on the objects you want to create/modify/delete, without concern for the underlying DB implementation?

Comment: I think for developers with a background in TSQL trying to accept and embrace ORM's, its a bit inefficient to lookup a record only to update it, and never utilize the fetched data.  This concept that a developer does not need to be concerned with the underlying DB implementation is a crock.  The more a developer knows about the entire system, the better the solution can be.  Options are never a bad thing.

Comment: This article as part of [Microsoft's Getting Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) explains entity states and how to do this: [Add/Attach and Entity States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676) Look at the section 'Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context' Now I'm off to read the rest of these tutorials.

Comment: The ORM approach is fine for actual objects, but if you also store other things in your database (like large binary blobs) it can be super useful to be able to update them without loading the original contents first.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

***Update**: If you're using EF Core 7.0+, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74208246/7734384).*

You should use the [Attach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487214.aspx) method.

[Attaching and Detaching Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx)

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: context.Products.Attach(product);
context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: @Gabriel Won't this update all properties though? What if I only want to modify a single one?

Comment: Yes this will update all properties. If you want to update a single property you can do this: context.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Property).IsModified = true; (have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5567616/57369)

Comment: I would just like to add that context.Entry() is only available in .net 4.1, if you are still using 4.0 (like me) then check this out for the alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113434/where-is-context-entry  which is essentially: context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(yourObject, EntityState.Modified);

Comment: Here is a really good answer that uses Attach() http://stackoverflow.com/a/17442858/2498426

Comment: @Jerther that's good, but I also like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15339512/1175496 . I really hope someone can edit this answer here and give an example...

Comment: to think that MS didn't provide a simple `update where`

Comment: To save only updated properties, Attach() then update your properties then save

Answer (score 60):

## Now native support for this in EF Core 7 — [`ExecuteUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete):

Finally! After a long wait, EF Core 7.0 now has a *natively supported* way to run `UPDATE` (and also `DELETE`) statements while also allowing you to use arbitrary LINQ queries (`.Where(u => ...)`), without having to first retrieve the relevant entities from the database: **The new built-in method called `ExecuteUpdate`** — see ["What's new in EF Core 7.0?"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates) and the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete).

`ExecuteUpdate` is precisely meant for these kinds of scenarios, it can operate on any `IQueryable` instance, and lets you update specific columns on any number of rows, while always issuing a *single* `UPDATE` statement behind the scenes, making it as efficient as possible.

### Usage:

Imagine you wanted to update the `Email` column of a specific user:

```cs
dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == someId)
    .ExecuteUpdate(b =>
        b.SetProperty(u => u.Email, "NewEmail@gmail.com")
    );
```

As you can see, calling `ExecuteUpdate` requires you to make calls to the `SetProperty` method, to specify which property to update, and also what new value to assign to it.

EF Core will translate this into the following `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
UPDATE [u]
    SET [u].[Email] = "NewEmail@gmail.com"
FROM [Users] AS [u]
WHERE [u].[Id] = someId
```

#### Also, [`ExecuteDelete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete#executedelete) for deleting rows:

There's also a counterpart to `ExecuteUpdate` called `ExecuteDelete`, which, as the name implies, can be used to delete a single or multiple rows at once without having to first fetch them.

##### Usage:

```cs
// Delete all users that haven't been active in 2022:
dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.LastActiveAt.Year < 2022)
    .ExecuteDelete();
```

Similar to `ExecuteUpdate`, `ExecuteDelete` will generate `DELETE` SQL statements behind the scenes — in this case, the following one:

```sql
DELETE FROM [u]
FROM [Users] AS [u]
WHERE DATEPART(year, [u].[LastActiveAt]) < 2022
```

---

**Other notes:**

- Keep in mind that both `ExecuteUpdate` and `ExecuteDelete` are "terminating", meaning that the update/delete operation will take place as soon as you call the method. You're not supposed to call `dbContext.SaveChanges()` afterwards.
- If you're curious about the `SetProperty` method, and you're confused as to why `ExectueUpdate` doesn't instead receive a member initialization expression (e.g. `.ExecuteUpdate(new User { Email = "..." })`, then refer to [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/795#issuecomment-1202086328) (and the surrounding ones) on the GitHub issue for this feature.
- Furthermore, if you're curious about the rationale behind the naming, and why the prefix `Execute` was picked (there were also other candidates), refer to [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/795#issuecomment-1199865766), and the preceding (rather long) conversation.
- Both methods also have `async` equivalents, named `ExecuteUpdateAsync`, and `ExecuteDeleteAsync` respectively.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing this, somehow I haven't seen it so far.

Comment: @VPetrovic Happy to help! It's understandable, the feature hasn't been properly documented yet ([hopefully will](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/4333)) which is why many people aren't aware of it yet, but it is fully supported in EF Core 7.0+.

Comment: What if the new value of my property is dependent on its original value? Something like incrementing an int column. I can't do `b.SetProperty(u => u.Counter, u.Counter + 1)`

Comment: @swinn You can do that. Pass an expression as the second argument to `SetProperty`; like so: `b.SetProperty(u => u.Counter, u => u.Counter + 1)`. This sort of usage is demonstrated in the official article I linked to — see [the first example in this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#basic-executeupdate-examples).

Comment: how to handle situation when no entry is found to update ? for eg: x.Id => id when id doesn't exist.

Comment: @AdharshM What do you mean "how to handle"? What is your scenario exactly? The number of updated rows is returned as an `int` by the `ExecuteUpdate` method, if that's relevant to your problem. But I'm not sure I quite understand it.

Comment: @AradAlvand I think you've answered the question, I meant, when there is nothing that matches our condition in db, throw an error or something

Comment: @Adharsh Both `ExecuteUpdate` and `ExecuteDelete` return an `int` representing the number of affected rows. If that number is 0, then it means no rows in the database matched your `WHERE` clause. So, you can simply check if the returned number is 0 and throw any exception you want.

Comment: Nice! Finally we don't need 3th party libs like Zack.EFCore.Batch to do this anymore.

Answer (score 48):

You can also use direct SQL against the database using the context of the datastore.  Example:

```
dataEntity.ExecuteStoreCommand
   ("UPDATE items SET itemstatus = 'some status' WHERE id = 123 ");
```

For performance reasons, you may want to pass in variables instead of a single hard coded SQL string.  This will allow SQL Server to cache the query and reuse with parameters.  Example:

```
dataEntity.ExecuteStoreCommand
   ("UPDATE items SET itemstatus = 'some status' WHERE id = {0}", new object[] { 123 });
```

**UPDATE - for EF 6.0**

```
dataEntity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
       ("UPDATE items SET itemstatus = 'some status' WHERE id = {0}", new object[] { 123 });
```

Comment: why would you downgrade this answer without leaving a comment.  This suggestion addresses the original authors question spot-on.

Comment: `ExecuteStoreCommand` is not really an EF way of doing this, it's just using the `DbConnection` contained inside the `DbContext` to execute a command.  It's not database agnostic, let alone persistence agnostic (e.g. this example would crash if the OP switched to XML).

Comment: @just.another.programmer - with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Does it have to be persistence agnostic ?  It's not like you gonna change your storage system every other day.

Comment: I needed this answer. It was simple and exactly what I needed to update 2 tables. Funny how all over the place there is a ton of HowTos for MVC that seem to be written in Egyptian Hyrogliphs (sic). The guy didn't ask for anything but this.

Comment: You might change your storage system several times a day, in fact -- especially if you're doing proper unit testing. (i.e. if your unit tests run against in-memory DBSets, and F5 runs against SQL DB...) -- Writing raw SQL is terrible here, it basically means you can't test this code EXCEPT against a real SQL database. -- You should be doing this the proper way, with Entity Framework's `.IsModified` property.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 - try using EF across link servers that only support OpenQuery - lots of fun.  Sometimes you absolutely need raw SQL to get the job done.  Not always can you draw the code into isolation for testing.  Its not a perfect world out there.

Comment: @DvS - its not a perfect world out there.  I am merely pointing out an option.  I am not advocating when to use this option.  I agree hard coding is not a good practice.  Sometimes it is a last resort.  In the case of a last resort - at least this option exists and for that - this is a great answer.

Comment: Oh, you'd be surprised. For some absolutely insane reason, people think EF means you can easily switch the underlying database technology on a whim to same costs.  Nevermind all the sprocs and other T-SQL specific features. These ORMs make it easy to build upon different database technologies... but not switch between two different ones without tons and tons of work and irreplaceable feature gaps (e.g. bulk insert mapper for EF that has no MySQL equivalent).

Comment: How does this work if your parameter Is a string? do you need to put the `' '` around the  `{0}` like so `'{0}'`

Comment: `EF ` way of doing it is dumb

Answer (score 45):

The code:

```
ExampleEntity exampleEntity = dbcontext.ExampleEntities.Attach(new ExampleEntity { Id = 1 });
exampleEntity.ExampleProperty = "abc";
dbcontext.Entry<ExampleEntity>(exampleEntity).Property(ee => ee.ExampleProperty).IsModified = true;
dbcontext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

The result TSQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[ExampleEntities]
SET [ExampleProperty ] = @0
WHERE ([Id] = @1)
',N'@0 nvarchar(32),@1 bigint',@0='abc',@1=1
```

Note:

The "IsModified = true" line, is needed because when you create the new ExampleEntity object (only with the Id property populated) all the other properties has their default values (0, null, etc). If you want to update the DB with a "default value", the change will not be detected by entity framework, and then DB will not be updated.

In  example:

```
exampleEntity.ExampleProperty = null;
```

will not work without the line "IsModified = true", because the property ExampleProperty, is already null when you created the empty ExampleEntity object, you needs to say to EF that this column must be updated, and this is the purpose of this line.

Comment: This is perfect.  I just tested this and it is exactly what I wanted.  I want the changes to go through the EF infrastructure (including using EntityFramework.Triggers project) but wanted to be able to change 1 column with only having the primary key.

Answer (score 14):

If the `DataItem` has fields EF will pre-validate (like non-nullable fields), we'll have to disable that validation for this context:

```
DataItem itemToUpdate = new DataItem { Id = id, Itemstatus = newStatus };
dataEntity.Entry(itemToUpdate).Property(x => x.Itemstatus).IsModified = true;
dataEntity.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
dataEntity.SaveChanges();
//dataEntity.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
```

Otherwise we can try satisfy the pre-validation and still only update the single column:

```
DataItem itemToUpdate = new DataItem
{
    Id = id,
    Itemstatus = newStatus,
    NonNullableColumn = "this value is disregarded - the db original will remain"
};
dataEntity.Entry(itemToUpdate).Property(x => x.Itemstatus).IsModified = true;
dataEntity.SaveChanges();
```

Assuming `dataEntity` is a `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

You can verify the query generated by adding this to the `DbContext`:

```
/*dataEntity.*/Database.Log = m => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(m);
```

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

Updating using Entity Framework Core can be very slow if you need to update hundreds or thousands of entities with the same expression. Entities are first loaded in the context before being updated which is very bad for the performance and then, they are updated one by one which makes the update operation even worse.

EF+ Batch Update updates multiple rows using an expression in a single database roundtrip and without loading entities in the context.

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.

// UPDATE all users inactive for 2 years
var date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2);
ctx.Users.Where(x => x.LastLoginDate < date)
         .Update(x => new User() { IsSoftDeleted = 1 });
```

Comment: My god, I need this

Answer (score 3):

## Simple and elegant extension method:

I've written an extension method for `DbContext` that does exactly what the OP asked for.

In addition to that, it only requires you to provide a member initialization expression (e.g. `new User { ... }`), and it then figures out on its own what properties you've changed, so you won't have to specify them by hand:

```cs
public static void UpdateEntity<TEntity>(
    this DbContext context,
    int id,
    Expression<Func<TEntity>> updateExpression
) where TEntity : BaseEntity, new()
{
    if (updateExpression.Body is not MemberInitExpression memberInitExpr)
        throw new ArgumentException("The update expression should be a member initialization.");

    TEntity entityToUpdate = updateExpression.Compile().Invoke();
    entityToUpdate.Id = id;
    context.Attach(entityToUpdate);

    var updatedPropNames = memberInitExpr.Bindings.Select(b => b.Member.Name);
    foreach (string propName in updatedPropNames)
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).Property(propName).IsModified = true;
}
```

You also need a `BaseEntity` class or interface that has your primary key in it, like:

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

## Usage:

Here's how you'd use the method:

```cs
dbContext.UpdateEntity(1234 /* <- this is the ID */, () => new User
{
    Name = "New Name",
    Email = "TheNewEmail@gmail.con",
});
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Nice and simple! :D

And here's the resulting SQL that gets generated by Entity Framework:

```sql
UPDATE [Users]
SET [Name] = @p0, [Email] = @p1
WHERE [Id] = @p2;
```

### Limitation:

This method only allows you to update a single row using its primary key.
So, it doesn't work with `.Where(...)`, `IQueryable<...>`, and so on. If you don't have the PK, or you want to bulk-update, then this wouldn't be your best option. In general, if you have more complex update operations, then I'd recommend you use Entity Framework Plus, or similar libraries.

Comment: Looks good and could be useful, although there are some limitations. It requires entities to inherit from `BaseEntity` to have `Id` as key. And it may violate validation, which is always a caveat with stubs.

Comment: @GertArnold Hi :) Regarding the `BaseEntity` inheritance, that was not a problem for me as all my entity classes already inherited from a base class like that. But if somebody doesn't want to have a base class at all, I think they can either use reflection in the `UpdateEntity` method to set the property that corresponds to the PK (if there's such a property across all their entities, of course), or the `UpdateEntity` method could have an additional parameter with which you could specify which property on the object is the PK; like `dbContext.UpdateEntity(u => u.Id, 1234, new User { ... })`.

Comment: @GertArnold And regarding the validation thing, so far as I know it's not a problem in EF Core. Take the example in my answer, for instance. `User.Name` is a required property/column, but if you don't assign a value to it when calling the `UpdateEntity` method (which obviously means that it's going to have its default value `null`), everything will work as expected, and EF will not throw a validation error, So, unless I've misunderstood what you're referring to, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

**ef core 7 and above :**

```
public async Task<int> Update(UpdateLevelVm vm)
{
    return await _db.Levels.Where(l => l.Id == vm.LevelId)
        .ExecuteUpdateAsync(u => u
         .SetProperty(l => l.GradeId, vm.GradeId)
         .SetProperty(l => l.Title, vm.Title)
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works somewhat different in EF Core:

There may be a faster way to do this in EF Core, but the following ensures an UPDATE without having to do a SELECT (tested with EF Core 2 and JET on the .NET Framework 4.6.2):

Ensure your model does not have IsRequired properties

Then use the following template (in VB.NET):

```
    Using dbContext = new MyContext()
        Dim bewegung = dbContext.MyTable.Attach(New MyTable())
        bewegung.Entity.myKey = someKey
        bewegung.Entity.myOtherField = "1"

        dbContext.Entry(bewegung.Entity).State = EntityState.Modified
        dbContext.Update(bewegung.Entity)

        Dim BewegungenDescription = (From tp In dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes() Where tp.ClrType.Name = "MyTable" Select tp).First()
        For Each p In (From prop In BewegungenDescription.GetProperties() Select prop)
            Dim pp = dbContext.Entry(bewegung.Entity).Property(p.Name)
            pp.IsModified = False
        Next
        dbContext.Entry(bewegung.Entity).Property(Function(row) row.myOtherField).IsModified = True
        dbContext.SaveChanges()
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of EF Core (starting from 7.x), there is a new and more efficient way to update rows without the need of writing any SQL query directly in code.
This can be achieved by making use of the newly added `ExecuteUpdate()` extension method.

You can use it as follows:

`dbContext.Entities.ExecuteUpdateAsync(x => x.SetProperty(c => c.PropertyName, c => "NewPropertyValue"));`

You can read more about it in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7#use-executeupdate-and-executedelete-when-relevant

Answer (score -3):

this has worked for me in EF core 3.1

```
await _unitOfWork.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("UPDATE Student SET Age = 22 Where StudentId = 123");
```