# Updating record in EF 4.1

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have an employee object say:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
    public int Address {get; set;}

 ...other few 10's of properties
}
```

The question is how do I only update Name? For eg. If I want to update Name I do

```
Employee e = Db.Employees.Where(e => e.Id == someId).SingleOrDefault();
e.Name = "Jack";
Db.SaveChanges();
```

As you can see, for updating I have to first get the object and then update and then call SaveChanges(). For a task that can be done in a single query to a database I have to fire of 2 queries: 1) Get the object 2) update the required object and save changes.

For traditional stored procedure approach I would just pass the Id, pass the new Name and write Update statement and I am done. Is Entity Framework really that inefficient or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe that this: [C# Entity Framework: Can I update a record without querying first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218566/c-sharp-entity-framework-can-i-update-a-record-without-querying-first) answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update columns selectively:

```
var employee = new Employee() { Id = someId, Name = "Jack" }
Db.Employees.Attach(employee);
Db.Employees.Entry(employee).Property(e => e.Name).IsModified = true;

Db.SaveChanges();
```

Note: Only EF 5 with .NET 4.5 supports setting `IsModified` back to `false`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also modify the answer for delete? How do I change the above code to delete entity? Can I just do an attach and then remove from DBSet<Employee> and call SaveChanges? Would that work?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx) method

```
var e = new Employee() { Id = someId, Name = "Jack" }
Db.Employees.Attach(e);
Db.Employees.Entry(e).Property(p => p.Name).IsModified = true

Db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What about the other properties? Like address etc? would they preserve as it is or would they all become null?

Comment: Updated, same answer with Ladislav