# Want to use EF core 6 in with .Net core Web API on huge legacy SQL server database

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

In my database, there are approximately 200 tables, many of which contain over 100 column each. Attachments are stored in the database, resulting in each row containing substantial data. A row may contain up to 200 MB, with an average of 50 MB per row in some tables. I intend to use EF Core 6 to develop a REST API for a mobile application. Is this approach viable for this requirement, or should I use ADO.NET with raw queries? Are there any performance issues associated with using EF Core?

I want to use EF core to learn new technology.

Comment: Using EF Core for a REST API with large datasets is viable for learning purposes, but potential performance issues may arise due to less optimized queries and memory consumption. Careful data loading strategies and query optimization are necessary to mitigate these issues. Consider using EF Core's features like query optimization and caching, and profile your application to identify and address performance bottlenecks. While EF Core offers productivity benefits, weighing the trade-offs between productivity, performance, and learning goals is crucial.

Comment: If you will write your queries carefully, i.e. select only necessary columns, limit result set with where clauses and top, etc., Entity Framework will be just fine. It is here to make your life easier :) If you hit any perf bottlenecks with EF, you can dive deeper, for example use raw queries, which EF allows as well. So I don't see anything wrong with such approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to check the following things:

1. Scaffold database and measure speed of first executed query. EF Core have performnce issue with big Model, which can be solved by [Compiled models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant#compiled-models)
2. For update record, you have to load record from database fully or play with partial [Update tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44459225/10646316), `ExecuteUpdate` one of them, but you have to use at least EF Core 7
3. For updating records with big blobs, you may use [Table splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting) - note that if you plan to Scaffold periodically from database, it should be reconfigured again.

Not too much benefits without knowledge what you are trying to do with database via EF Core.

Comment: Just to let you know, consensus is to answer "well-asked" questions only, see [answer].

Comment: @GertArnold, what to do with this? Delete?

Comment: I don't know. It's a rather soft criterium. IMO you can leave it here now you posted it. It's also an indirect hint to OP to look at [ask] before asking any new questions.