# Update all children entities, EF/Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two tables A and B. Their relation is 1:N.
I want to update one field in ALL the children tables, but I'm don't know what LINQ expression to use to do that -- shouldn't be too difficult.

I was thinking something like:

```
parentEntity.childrens.All(..lambda expr..).field = value;
```

But obviously it's not working.

I know the other option is a foreach(..), but I'd prefer L2E if possible.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2011/11/29/entity-framework-batch-update-and-future-queries.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't set a property on all items of a collection without somehow looping through that collection, either with `foreach`, `for`, `List<T>.ForEach`, or similar.

If you want to keep it in one line, you could do something like:

```
author.Books.ToList().ForEach(b => b.PublishYear = 1999);
```

Comment: I agree. Linq is fundamentally a QUERY language; it is meant to query a collection without changing it. I would make the query and then foreach over the items you've queried as a separate statement.

Comment: I was traying not to move the entire collection to memory, but you both are right. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to either loop through and update all or use a raw `SQL` statement executed through `Entity Framework` which would be much more efficient for this kind of thing.

Comment: As this answer indicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework/3642383#3642383