# Entity framework and ObjectContext.SaveChanges()

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

In datatables with ADO.NET an updatecommand updates full row.That means that even if you change 1 cell all collumns of the row would be updated... This is not the problem always.
However although reading from msdn i couldnt find whether this this true for Entity Framework. Updating a property would create a full update sql query or only for the column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this tested and verified answer [How to update only one field using Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework/3642383#3642383) only updated fields are updated in sql not the entire object.

Answer (score 0):

Hasan is correct, only changed fields are updated and this is easy to confirm by tracing the SQL in the SQL Profiler (or equivalent tool)