# How do I stop ValueInjecter from mapping null values?

Tags: c#, mapping, valueinjecter

I am using ValueInjecter to map two identical objects. The problem I am having is that ValueInjector copies null values from my source over my target. So I am loosing lots of data to null values.

Here's an example of my object which is sometimes only half filled out which results in its null values overwriting the target object.

```
public class MyObject()
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OtherObject> OtherObjects { get; set; }
}

to.InjectFrom(from);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom ConventionInjection in this case. See example #2:
http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=step%20by%20step%20explanation&referringTitle=Home

So, you'll need to override the Match method:

```
protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c){
    //Use ConventionInfo parameter to access the source property value
    //For instance, return true if the property value is not null.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those using `ValueInjecter` v3+, `ConventionInjection` has been deprecated. Use following to achieve same results:

```
public class NoNullsInjection : LoopInjection
{
    protected override void SetValue(object source, object target, PropertyInfo sp, PropertyInfo tp)
    {
        if (sp.GetValue(source) == null) return;
        base.SetValue(source, target, sp, tp);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
target.InjectFrom<NoNullsInjection>(source);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this.

```
public class NoNullsInjection : ConventionInjection
{
    protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
    {
        return c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name
                && c.SourceProp.Value != null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
target.InjectFrom(new NoNullsInjection(), source);
```