# How to prevent user from modifying some fields on the form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using MVC3 and EF4 to write a web application. I am using an action header like below to capture the form values submitted by the user.

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function Edit(ByVal prod as Product) As ActionResult
```

I use the below code for updating the record.

```
db.Attach(prod)
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(prod, EntityState.Modified)
db.SaveChanges()
```

I get the submitted values in prod object which I update in the database. The problem is that there are some users who are not allowed to modify certain fields in a Product, say ProductCost. I have disabled the textboxes for such fields in the HTML. But since it is clientside, the user can easily enable it using some tool like Firebug and modify the value.

The only solution I could come up was to retrieve the existing record from the database and copy its ProductCost value into prod.ProductCost. But I don't like firing a query for achieving this. Is there a better way to achieve this?

**Edit**: I found the below link to update particular fields. [How to update only one field using Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework)

You can use the below code to modify a particular field.

```
context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(user).SetModifiedProperty("FieldName");
```

Now the question is do I have to write the above statement for every field the user is able to modify? If yes, suppose the Product model has 10 fields (1 primary key) and the user is allowed to modify all of them except the primary key, I need to write 9 statements?? Is there a method where you can specify multiple properties at once. Or even better something where you specify the properties which are not modified. (Note: I know I can run a loop over an array of field names to avoid writing 9 statements. I am asking for an alternative method and not refactoring the above)

Answer (score 2):

**Never trust client data.** Always have your server code to validate the input and do appropriate actions.

I would create separate **overloads** of my Respiratory method update the product in different ways and then check what is the current user's access type, If he is admin, i will call the overload which updates everything, if he is a manager, i will call the method which updates name,imageUrl and price and if he is an employee, i will call the method which updates only name and ImageURL

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Product prod)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid) 
  {
    string userType=GetCurrentUserTypeFromSomeWhere();
    if(userType=="admin")
    {
       repo.UpdateProduct(prod);
    }
    else if(userType=="manager")
    {
       repo.UpdateProduct(prod.ID, prod.Name, prod.ImageUrl, prod.Price);
    } 
    else if(userType=="employee")
    {
       repo.UpdateProduct(prod.ID, prod.Name, prod.ImageUrl);
    } 
    return RedirectToAction("Updated",new {id=prod.ID});
  }

}
```

Comment: I am using the below code to update a record.
db.Attach(model)
                    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(model, EntityState.Modified)
                    db.SaveChanges()

My context object does not have any method like UpdateProduct.

Comment: @Cracker You have to load the existing product from the db and then (based on the usertype) only update the fields that the user has access to. That's what Shyju's repo.UpdateProduct(...) would do behind the scenes.

Comment: ok.. then I already know that method.. I am asking for alternatives