# Which namespace to include to strongly type the property with DbEntityEntry.Property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I can't seem to get the following code working.

I would like to use the following code

```
db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Password)
```

Instead of

```
db.Entry(user).Property("Password")
```

This is a code snippet from an answer which can be found here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework).

```
public void ChangePassword(int userId, string password)
{
  var user = new User() { Id = userId, Password = password };
  using (var db = new MyEfContextName())
  {
    db.Users.Attach(user);
    db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Password).IsModified = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

My current usings

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a namespace problem, but rather which overloaded version of `DbContext.Entry()` you use; the generic one or the non-generic one.

Try this:

```
db.Entry<User>(user).Property(x => x.Password)
```

Comment: My exact code.

`DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = context.Entry<TEntity>(entity); dbEntityEntry.Property("IsActive").IsModified = true;`

Comment: But yes, I used the generic one and it all went great! Thanks