# How to UPDATE only one column of an already loaded entity in the Db?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I want to load an entity from the and set only one property and Update it in the Db but only by updating the property I have changed.

How can I achieve that?

```
var goodFood = Repository.FoodRepository.GetByID(100);
good.Food.SaltLevel = Salt.NoSalt;

// Now how to SAve it back without touching any other fields 
//and only updating the SaltLevel field?
```

Comment: Just call `DataContext.Save()` ??

Comment: But I do not want it to override other fields. Bcoz other process running in parallel might have updated some other fields. But imagine SaltLevel is only updated from this piece of code.

Comment: you would encounter a concurrency exception if other fields changed since you loaded the entity

Comment: When the goodFood is loaded, some other app can already update some other fields (I tried to simplify with food example)

Comment: @Moho, this is what I doubt in my case...

Comment: @pencilCake - there's a slew of potential solutions for you in this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework).