# Update just one field in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have tried this tutorial, but it's not working for me ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework)), My objective is update just one field of my Entity... no other fields. I'm testing EntityFramework, and I would like to check if I can to do an automapper of a DTO and after update just one field.

I have tried this:

```
MyContext db = new MyContext();
MyClass sampleModel = new MyClass();
sampleModel.IdMyClass = "1d1ba1f2-8c08-c334-5486-08d16fecc6e3"; //GUID
sampleModel.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
db.MyClass.Attach(sampleModel);
db.Entry(sampleModel).Property(x => x.ModificationDate).IsModified = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

**MyClass Class**

```
public partial class MyClass 
{
    public string IdMyClass { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public System.DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OtherClass> OtherClass{ get; set; }        
}
```

**MyClassMap**

```
public MyClassMap() : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyClass>
{
    //Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.IdMyClass);
    //Properties
    this.Property(t => t.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(256);

    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("MyClass");
    this.Property(t => t.IdMyClass).HasColumnName("IdMyClass");
    this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
    this.Property(t => t.ModificationDate).HasColumnName("ModificationDate");            
}
```

Where is my problem??

**Error details, It happens in db.SaveChanges()**

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities.
>   See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

EntityValidationErrors is empty...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: I think, **Name = null** on db.SaveChanges();

Comment: Yes, it's null, but now, I must access to the database to obtain the name?

Comment: You can attach an entity without having to request it from the DB.

Comment: @Rodrigo - Ah yea, you right.

Comment: Really? I can't do a "update" without do before a "select?

Comment: No sorry, don't listen to me. @Rodrigo is right. You can attach it like you're doing. Just assign the name before attaching.

Comment: But if I don't know and I want to maintance the original value of the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define which properties will be updated with something like this:

```
MyContext db = new MyContext();
MyClass sampleModel = new MyClass();
sampleModel.IdMyClass = "1d1ba1f2-8c08-c334-5486-08d16fecc6e3"; //GUID
sampleModel.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
sampleModel.Name=string.Empty; //should not be needed
db.MyClass.Attach(sampleModel);
var entry=db.Entry(sampleModel);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
var excluded = new string[] { "Name" };
foreach (var name in excluded)
{
   entry.Property(name).IsModified = false;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Ok so here is my version of your code.
**The classes**

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public string IdMyClass { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OtherClass> OtherClass { get; set; }
}
public partial class OtherClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Stuff { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("MyContextDb")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OtherClass> OtherClasses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().ToTable("MyClass");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
            .HasKey(t => t.IdMyClass)
            .Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(t => t.IdMyClass).HasColumnName("IdMyClass");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(t => t.ModificationDate).HasColumnName("ModificationDate");

    }
}
```

*A simple console program to test the result*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyContext db = null; ;
        try
        {
            db = new MyContext();
            Foo(db);
            Console.WriteLine("Id\tDate\tName");
            foreach(var c in db.MyClasses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}",c.IdMyClass,c.ModificationDate,c.Name);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (db != null)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static void Foo(MyContext db)
    {
        var sampleModel = new MyClass();
        sampleModel.IdMyClass = "1d1ba1f2-8c08-c334-5486-08d16fecc6e3"; //GUID
        sampleModel.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
        sampleModel.Name = string.Empty; //should not be needed
        db.MyClasses.Attach(sampleModel);
        var entry = db.Entry(sampleModel);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        var excluded = new string[] { "Name" };
        foreach (var name in excluded)
        {
            entry.Property(name).IsModified = false;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: Ok, I will test later, Im out at home... But I think that it's so complex... I want to use in a API REST with a lot of DTOs... Thank you so much, if it's work I will vote your answer like good ;)

Comment: Ok, it's work, but sampleModel.Name=string.Empty; //should not be needed, IS NEEDED! :( I don't know why...