# Update entity partially fails on SaveChanges as of validation-errors for untouched fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to improve the performance when writing/changing data in the database using `EntityFramework 6`.

When fetching the entity to be updated I use the following code as I know the primary key from other entities foreign-key relation:

```
// create a dummy entity
var dummy = new TheEntity
{
    TheEntityId = myKey
};

// check if not already attached
var attachedEntity = dbContext.TheEntity.Exists(nrp => nrp.TheEntityId == myKey); // this checks if not already attached
if (attachedEntity == null)
{
    // attach to the context
    dbContext.TheEntity.Attach(dummy);
}

// return the dummy
return dummy;
```

Later I change some values of the entity (but only some) which can be different depending on the caller.

However, when `SaveChanges` is called I always get `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException`s for properties I did not touch.

What I want is an update-statement which only updates the values marked as `IsModified == true`.

I also checked the entry's properties with `dbContext.Entry(dummy).Property(...).IsModified` and only those I have changed are true but the other properties are `false` so they should not get updated, no?

What is wrong? As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework) it should work as expected.

I tried the answer as well as the comment 'If you don't want to set `db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false`...', but still the same issue. And I really do not want to disable validate.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without disabling ValidateOnSave, because validation procedure does not look if property was modified or not - just validates them all.

Comment: @Evk, thanks. I had a look at https://dennymichael.net/2016/02/03/entity-framework-validation-with-partial-updates/. Is this okay to do or are there any cases this could go completely wrong? Could not imagine such a case but may not see the whole picture here

Comment: Looks fine for me. Though if you want to be on a safe side, you can disable ValidateOnSave when you perform that partial update, then manually call ctx.GetValidationErrors() and filter them out.

Comment: Hi @KingKerosin why not to read this entity from Db and update that in this way you will have all properties and validation will not fail ?

Comment: @YashveerSingh, because for my understanding of better performance it is not necessary to fetch 20 properties/values from the db when I only want to change one or two. For this particluar problem I am not interested in the current values at all. But I know this is the way EF works... Maybe in EF7?