# Updating a single field in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to update a single field in ASP.Net MVC 5 I get error:

My Code:

```
  MyJobs.PublishStatus = 1;
  db.MyJobContext.Attach(MyJobs);
  db.Entry(MyJobs).Property(x => x.PublishStatus).IsModified = true;
  //db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
  db.SaveChanges();
```

I get bellow error:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). 
>       Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. 
>       See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and
>        handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

there is post regarding this error but I could not figure it out:
[Entity Framework: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec)

and updating single field in asp.net MVC from: [How to update only one field using Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework)

Comment: `MyJobs.PublishStatus = 1;` possibly already updating `PublishStatus` if `MyJobs` coming from a LINQ result set, so that when `Attach` is executed there are no rows to be updated anymore.

Comment: if you set `ValidateOnSaveEnabled` to false, it will work. I can see your code you already have that line, why did you comment it  ?

Comment: I tried that but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating my form and added the input hidden for Id field

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
     <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Publish" class="btn btn-default" />
     </div>
}
```

hope this will help someone who face the same issue.