# Entity Framework - Update only sending values

Tags: entity-framework

I want to update my entity for just sending values.

```
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateDepartment(Department department)
{
    var ok = _departmentDAL.Update(department);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ok);
}
```

Im sending just 2 value with postman to my api.
[image: postman]

In my generic repository base, my update function like.

```
public int Update(TEntity entity)
{
    var updatedEntity = _context.Entry(entity);
    updatedEntity.State = EntityState.Modified;

    return _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And I got entity validation error. Simply I just want to modify only **not null** values of entity.

Is it possible or should I take all entity with my Id property from database and then after changing the properties send to the entity framework ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update only one field using Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleanest solution is to not provide a general interface that can update any desired field of `Department`. Instead, provide an API that is tailored to the actual use cases you want to support. This API should receive **commands** that only contain the data allowed for the specific use case. Commands can also validate their data (here I use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` for validation). Also, you can handle authorization in a more granular way if the use cases are well defined and separated.

```
public class UpdateDepartmentDescriptionCommand {

    [Required, Range(1, long.MaxValue)]
    public long DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(256)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public HttpResponseMessage UpdateDepartmentDescription(UpdateDepartmentDescriptionCommand cmd) {

    // validate command
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(cmd, new ValidationContext(cmd, null, null), validationResults, true);

    if (!isValid) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, validationResults);
    }

    // retrieve Department from DB using the given ID
    var department = _departmentDAL.Find(cmd.DepartmentId);

    // only update values defined by the usecase
    department.Description = cmd.Description;

    var ok = _departmentDAL.Update(department);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ok);
}
```