# Update only some Model fields using generic Repository Entity Framework core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the Users Model follows:

Model Users.cs

```
    [Key]
    [Column("cod")]
    public int Cod { get; set; }
    [Column("nome")]
    [StringLength(120)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Column("sobrenome")]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
    [Column("email")]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Column("password")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

And I also have the ViewModel only with the data shown in View
UsersViewModel.cs

```
    public int Cod { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
```

My generic repository looks like this:

```
    public void Update(TEntity obj)
    {
        Db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

In my controller it looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SalvaPerfil([FromBody] UsersViewModel usersViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = Mapper.Map<UsersViewModel, Users>(usersViewModel);
            _PetApp.Update(user);
            return Content("fim...");
        }
        return Content("ERRO");
    }
```

The problem is that the Email and Password fields are being written as NULL in the database, I do not want to change the Email and Password values as they are changed in another View.

I saw this other post, but it is not with Generic Repository, I could not implement it ..

[How to update only one field using Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework)

In this case do I need to create a custom method for this change? or is there any way to only change the fields that are in the ViewModel?

Thanks!

Comment: Get the entity from database, update properties you need and save changes.

Comment: @MrgGek How would I do that? a foreach in "TEntify obj"? could you give me a practical example? thank you!

Comment: Select the entity from database by its Id. var entity = Db.Set(obj).FirstOrDefault(e => e. Cod == cod);
var user = entity as User; 
user.Name = "Changed";
 Update(user);

Comment: I understand what should be done, the problem is that my Repository is generic "public void Update (TEntity obj)", I do not know which Entity it is working on, I will create a custom method to update only a few fields of the entity while I keep searching. ..

Comment: I did what you checked me in the Controller, get the current user is updated the required fields .. thanks!