# Entity Framework API Put method, only update one column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework API and I am trying to update just one column using the Put method...

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        [Authorize]
        public IHttpActionResult PutLCTimeSlots(int id, LCTimeSlots lCTimeSlots)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != lCTimeSlots.id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(lCTimeSlots).State = EntityState.Modified;


            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!LCTimeSlotsExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

My question, what do I need to change in this method to only update one column?

I have tried replacing `db.Entry(lCTimeSlots).State = EntityState.Modified;` with `db.Entry(lCTimeSlots).Property(x => x.taken).IsModified = true;` But that didn't work....anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try  [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework)?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the default `PUT` for such an operation as it implies a client should be able to update more than a single property.  I'd suggest a `PUT` operation using a route that describes the property being updated w/ parameter of the property's type instead of an `LCTimeSlots` object:

```
[HttpPut( "{id}/yourProperty" )]
[Authorize]
public IHttpActionResult YourProperty( int id, TypeOfProperty yourProperty )
{
    // validate value of `yourProperty` if you can before loading entity from DB

    // load entity from DB
    var loadedEntity = dbContext.Set<LCTimeSlots>().Find( id );

    // if not found, 404 it

    // update property, e.g.: 
    loadedEntity.YourProperty = yourProperty;

    // validate entity in its entirety if necessary

    // save changes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by suggesting use of the PATCH verb if you only want to modify certain properties.

Also, it's not a great idea to accept an entity object from the client, instead accept a model object that only has the properties that you aim to modify with this method.

Lastly, verify that the entity exists **before** attempting to make any change.

Now, do something like this:

```
        var timeSlot = db.LCTimeSlots.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == model.Id);

        if (timeSlot != null)
        {
            db.Entry(timeSlot).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            //404
        }
```

Comment: So do I want to replace this line `db.Entry(lCTimeSlots).State = EntityState.Modified;` with your code?

Comment: @user979331 Yes -- you will be able to eliminate the try/catch as well.  But again I strongly suggest not directly accepting an entity object from a user (this gives a user the ability to modify any property on the object, which, depending on what you're doing, may even be a security risk.  Create a class having only the properties you want the user to be able to modify, and use that as the model.