# Assign One to many without running SELECT query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Lets say we have a :

```
class Zoo{
   Id;
   Name;
   List<Animal> Animals;

}
class Animal{
   Id;
   Name;
   ZooId;
}
```

Normally I would do

```
  var zooId=1;
  var animalId=1;
  var animal = db.Animals.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==animalId);
  animal.ZooId=zooId;
  db.SaveChanges();
```

Correct me if I am wrong,but the ef.core would run a Select query and then an update query.

Is there a way to write a code which would produce a single SQL query like:

```
'Update Animal Set ZooId=1 where Id=1'
```

(Preferably by using lambda code)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating it as below. First create object with assigning valid `animalId` and set `ZooId` as your requirement. With `Property(x => x.ZooId).IsModified = true;` it will only update `ZooId`.

```
var animal = new Animal() 
{ 
    Id = 1,
    ZooId = 1
}
db.Animals.Attach(animal).Property(x => x.ZooId).IsModified = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Hopefully this link will be helpful [How to update only one field using Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567616/9695286)