# Renumbering database rows is inefficient

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My database has a `Task` table with a `Sequence` column. The `Sequence` column specifies the order of the tasks.

In some cases, I need to change the order. So I would use something like this:

```
var tasks = (dbContext.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.UserId == userId)).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
{
    // Set new sequence
    tasks[i].Sequence = i;
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This seems rather inefficient to have to retrieve every column of every `Task` in the set.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

*Note: Please don't get caught up in the fact that I'm simply setting `Sequence` to `i` in the code above. The real code will have data receive data that indicates the correct values. But if I could optimize the code above, I could then adapt it to my final needs.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update only one field using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework)

Comment: Sorry, forgot my single vote to close would close the question. Please let me know if I got it wrong!

Comment: @RufusL: The technique shown for that question creates the data in memory. My code needs to update the `Sequence` column. That means I first need to read that column. So the proposed answer doesn't really address my question.

Comment: @stuartd: If you look closer at my code, I'm updating the `Sequence` column. I'm not sorting the results.

Comment: Right, you would add a `.Select(t => t.Sequence)` to your query to pull in only that column, then use those results to update the database. But I don't mind re-opening the question.

Comment: @RufusL: Looks like I reopened the question. I don't quite understand where this `Select()` would go. The answers for that question simply create an in-memory object. Using a `Select()` instead would change the entire thing. I guess I'm not following you.

Comment: `var tasks = dbContext.Tasks.Where(t => t.UserId == userId).Select(t => new Task { UserId = userId, Sequence = t.Sequence });` might work - I can't test it right now. I think this will just query the single column, and then you can use the answer in the possible duplicate to update just that column.

Comment: @RufusL: I see. I can play with that. I'm a little unsure about what exactly would get saved when I call `SaveChanges()`. Thanks.

Comment: For efficient approach, you should push the data to server at once (bulk insert or TVP) and update the table with single update command. I am not sure if EF can do that.

Comment: I'll post what I *think* would work, but I'm not certain about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pull down only the column you want to update by using a `Select` statement, and then, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework), update just that column.

This example might work, but unfortunately I can't test it right now:

```
// Query just a single column
var tasks = dbContext.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.UserId == userId)
    .Select(t => new Task { UserId = t.UserId, Sequence = t.Sequence })
    .ToList();

// Update a single column and tell EF to track it
for(int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
{
    tasks[i].Sequence = i;
    dbContext.Attach(tasks[i]);
    dbContext.Entry(tasks[i]).Property(t => t.Sequence).IsModified = true;
}

// Save the changes to that column
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This seems to work once I added the PK to the `Select()` clause. Unfortunately, it appears to require separate queries for each row but perhaps there's no way around that.